# what is the logic behind it? how output came

Tags: c++

In `c++`, I am not able to understand this code logic. Can someone explain it?
Output is `0 3 5 7 9 11 13 15`, mainly `if(i&1){continue}` logic behind it.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


int main(){

   for(int i = 0; i<=15; i+=2){
       cout<<i<<" ";

       if(i&1){
           continue;
       }

       i++;
   }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i&1` checks if [LSB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering#LSB_0_bit_numbering) is set. For all odd numbers, LSB is 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i & 1` performs a bitwise AND between `i` and `1`. So if `i == 13`, then you are performing:

```
     1101
AND  0001
---------
     0001
```

So when `i == 13`, `if(i & 1)` would be essentially `if(1)` or `if(true)`.

Similarly, if `i == 10`, `1010 AND 0001 = 0000`, so `if(i & 1)` would be essentially `if(false)`.

---

Now you might see a pattern, what you are doing is [querying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)#Querying_the_status_of_a_bit) the right most bit of `i`, or the [LSB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering#Bit_significance_and_indexing) of `i`, which can also be used to test if `i` is an odd number.